# "missing ; before statement" error for getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, json

Can someone please explain the following.  I've scoured the net for ages trying to find help and I believe I'm doing everything correctly but still getting errors.

I have the following script on my page:

```
        function GetPageAdvert2(url) {

            $.getJSON('http://url/servicename.asmx/CheckAdvert?callback=?', 
            {
                pagename:   url,
                success:    function(data) { alert(data) }
            });        
        };
```

And my webservice returns nothing more than:

```
jsonp1301065851157('url/KiN_150x300.jpg');
```

The problem is that when I call GetPageAdvert2, nothing is happening.

My WebService (written in VB.Net) is:

```
        <WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
Public Sub CheckAdvert(ByVal pagename As String, ByVal callback As String)

    Dim pageUID As Integer = 0
    Dim advertURL As List(Of aU) = New List(Of aU)()

    Dim sss As String

    Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.sqlConnection2)

           SQL STUFF IN HERE
           the SELECT statement will return a value and place it in Variable SSS


    End Using

    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    Context.Response.Write(callback & "('" & sss & "');")
    Context.Response.End()


End Function
```

The response I'm getting back (in FF) is:

```
PARAMS:
callback    jsonp1300979718942
contentType application/json; charset=utf-8
pagename    default.html
success undefined

RESPONSE:
jsonp1301065851157('url/KiN_150x300.jpg');
```

This is mostly, what I believe, to be correct.

However the "Alert(data)" isn't producing anything other than "undefined".

Comment: JSON should start and end with curly braces: {"url":"KiN_150x300.jpg"}

Comment: @Oscar: that's not true: in this case, the server returns an object wrapped in an array.

Comment: @Oscar: Incorrect. That is if you only want to return a single object. If you want to return an array you start with surround it with `[]`.

Comment: Ok, now you need to replace `test` with the `callback` parameter. If you define a `function test(a) { alert(a); }` now, does it alert something like `[object Object]`?

Comment: No, I'm getting a 200 OK (error) in FireBug.  Likewise I don't know what the callback parameter is going to be as it's a random number (see edited post), I think it's like a Unix Timestamp.

Comment: So, does it work now, or do you still get an error? The callback parameter is a function name, that gets called as soon as the script is injected in your page.

Comment: No, sorry, still getting an error (missing ; ).  Thing is, the "Success" I think is being called as that's the ONLY Alert box I have in my script and it is showing "undefined".

Comment: Ah, now it's more clear (please indent code by 4 spaces using the code `{}` button): the server responds with an XML document, not with a plain JavaScript statement `jsonp1300979718942([{"url":"[removed]/KiN_150x300.jpg"}])`. See if you can get rid of the rest. What server-side language do you use?

Comment: @Marcel, I'm glad it's more clear to you because it's not to me! haha. OK, well I've indented the code by 4 spaces, the response I get back (from FireBug) now reads "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string xmlns="[url/">jsonp1301039560625( [{"url":"url/KiN_150x300.jpg"}])</string>" yet I'm still getting the "missing ;" error. The server-side language is VB.Net. I've updated my original post with what's there.

Comment: No, the indenting is meant for *this* site, not for *your* code on the server. The problem is VB.net related: you should probably just "print" the string `jsonp1301039560625([{"url":"url/KiN_150x300.jpg"}])` to the client, you shouldn't output an XML document, as the server does at the moment.

Comment: @Marcel - Finally solved it.  Will edit my above post to show what I've done.  THANK YOU for your help and assistance, it's certainly been an insight, and while I'm not 100% convinced my solution works for everything (maybe it will fail at an array?), it's certainly helped me understand.  Again my sincere thanks for your patience in this.

Comment: @Marcel, now armed with the fact I'm returning a JavaScript call, how is that now possible to return the value to my original call on the client?  The "Success" part of the getJSON doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: By looking at your current code, it seems you're outputting `test(`, but you should output the value of the `callback` parameter, so something like `Context.Response.Write(callback & "(" & js.Serialize(sss) & ")")` should suffice.

Comment: @Marcel, ok have done that and getting NO errors at all.  The response sure enough is now "jsonp1301060523484('url/KiN_150x300.jpg');" but that's all it does!  Everything you're saying is making sense so far, it's just the final bit I'm struggling with - i.e. getting the data back to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), you can't simply return a JSON string, as the string returned will actually get injected into the current page in a new `script` element. You need to return a valid JavaScript statement that calls a callback handler, in which the response is parsed.

There's an example on the Wikipedia page:

```
parseResponse({"Name": "Cheeso", Id : 1823, "Rank": 7})
```

Note that above syntax is not valid JSON, which is in this case not needed, as you only pass a JavaScript object in literal notation.

Moreover, as x10 said in his comment, jQuery changes the `?` in the `callback` query parameter to a unique function, which you should call, so don't just copy-paste the above example, but replace `parseResponse` with the mentioned parameter.

**Update:** the final thing you should change are the parameters to [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/): the syntax looks like:

> ```
> jQuery.getJSON( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )
> ```

So you should just pass your success function as the second or third parameter, not as part of an object (compare this to the general [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function call):

```
$.getJSON("***URL***.asmx/CheckAdvert?callback=?", function(data) { callback(data) });
```

Comment: Also: Instead of "parseResponse", your server-side code should write the function name given in the 'callback' HTTP parameter. When you pass 'callback=?' jQuery automatically creates a function with a unique name and sends that name as the 'callback' parameter of the request. That function is actually the handler you passed to getJSON, so if you don't pass the proper name it won't get executed.

Comment: after an entire weekend of reading about this, have now got it working.  MANY thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think your function should look like:

```
function GetPageAdvert2(url) {
            $.getJSON("***URL HERE***.asmx/CheckAdvert?callback=?", 
            {
               pagename:  url,
               success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
               }
            });        
        }
```

Note that the success is a property of the getJSON. You had it outside

Comment: No, look at the syntax of [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/); you're intermingling this function with the general [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)